# Changing Time Zone on Azure Web Apps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, azure, localization, globalization

We have a multi tenant (row level) app in ASP.Net MVC5 C# + EF6 + SQL Server, that stores date/time in DateTime fields against a user's record. This used to present dates and times in the users timezone.

Now we're hosting the application in Azure, which records all date/times in UTC. 
I've a Tenant table, in which am thinking to tie the timezone against. Each tenant should always belong to respective timezone.

Using **TimeZoneInfo**, what would be the best way to display the datetime field across the application in specific timezone? Rather then converting dates in each view/model/report, can I create some global class?

And when I commit back the dates to database,  will convert them to UTC. I have override the **SaveChanges()**, hence I can intercept all dates and save it as UTC.

Just wondering a simple way [like using Application Settings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2015/04/06/changing-the-server-time-zone-on-azure-web-apps/) but at tenant level.